# Decrypt .m3u8 playlist and merge it into single .mp4 file with ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, encryption, video-conversion

I have a folder which contains `.key` file, `.m3u8` file and a bunch of `.ts` files.

My `.m3u8` looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="mykey.key"
#EXTINF:4.004000,
000000.ts
#EXTINF:4.004011,
000001.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
000002.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
000003.ts

...

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

What I want to do is to decrypt it and merge this playlist into a single .mp4 file

I tried this ffmpeg command on my Windows machine:

```
ffmpeg -i "myvid.m3u8" -codec copy output.mp4
```

But I get a following error:

```
[hls @ 000002780f0a8dc0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 000002780f0a8dc0] Filename extension of 'mykey.key' is not a common multimedia extension, blocked for security reasons.
If you wish to override this adjust allowed_extensions, you can set it to 'ALL' to allow all
[hls @ 000002780f0a8dc0] Unable to open key file mykey.key
[hls @ 000002780f0a8dc0] Opening 'crypto:000000.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000002780f0a8dc0] Opening 'crypto:000001.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000002780f0a8dc0] Error when loading first segment '000000.ts'
myvid.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I changed my command to following:

```
ffmpeg  -allowed_extensions ALL -i "myvid.m3u8" -codec copy output.mp4
```

Then I got this error:

```
[hls @ 000001a079cf8f80] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 000001a079cf8f80] Opening 'mykey.key' for reading
[hls @ 000001a079cf8f80] Opening 'crypto:000000.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001a079cf8f80] Opening 'crypto:000001.ts' for reading
[hls @ 000001a079cf8f80] Error when loading first segment '000000.ts'
myvid.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

If I open my `.key` file with text editor it shows weird symbols like `Ж‰еН:‘њ w†(„ым;§BgШ0чqо!I”q` I don't know if it supposed to look like this or not

At this point I don't really understand what the problem is.
Any idea how can I fix this?

I'm open to use any other software if this can't be done with ffmpeg or smth

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try using this
`ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,tls,tcp,https,crypto -allowed_extensions ALL -i myvid.m3u8 -c copy output.mp4`

> If I open my .key file with text editor it shows weird symbols like Ж‰еН:‘њ w†(„ым;§BgШ0чqо!I”q I don't know if it supposed to look like this or not

Yes, It is supposed to look like that.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.